# How can i save form.serialize value to a variable repeatedly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have add to cart button in my site. When button is clicked then the value in the form is store to a variable . `var cartData = $('form').serialize();`
My requirement is when the user select select next product in the page without refreshing , the form data need to save in `var cartData` without losing previous data,i.e i need to save this data as array. How can i do that. when i use `var cartData = $('form').serializeArray();` then the cartdata only contain new valus , not previous values of form serialize.

Comment: Have you tried merging the arrays ? Have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp)

Answer (score 3):

> form data need to save in var cartData without losing previous data,i.e i need to save this data as array

So you can push serialize result to actual array. For example:

```
var cartData = [];

// Save first form
cartData.push($('form').serialize());

// Later next form
cartData.push($('form').serialize());
```

This way you can store all forms you need in one data array.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But can you please tell me how can i check the result ?. How can i know both firs and second items are come in the array ?

Comment: You can access the first item as `cartData[0]`, the second `cartData[1]`, etc.

Comment: When i alert this cartData then the same values are repeating in both cartData[0] and  cartData[1]  . Please check this

Comment: Does form change when you push serialized string? I'm not sure about you logic, so you might want to add some details to the question about when you push this strings to array.

Comment: Yes.First i save value to variable , then i  reset the form using javascript .After that new form with new values are come .